# Google Spreadsheet changes my values from 00:00 to 00:00:00

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to input type in the following format:

```
00:00
```

However, it is automatically changed to

```
00:00:00
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can't you changed the data type of the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the cell/column/row and select Format (Menu) --> Number --> Normal (or any other format you'd like).

In your case I'd suggest to treat the cell as text, or as one of the additional formats in the sub-menu (for example `15:59 Time`).